# Does minimizing ANY type of energy ALWAYS predict a state of equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, energy, entropy

My intuition says no, but I am having trouble coming up with concrete examples.

I know that minimizing Gibbs free energy predicts a state of equilibrium, while minimizing kinetic or internal energy does not correspond to equilibrium. However, I am not so sure about potential energy--- when PE is at a minimum, is the system also at equilibrium?

Comment: If you write a wavefunction of H$_2^+$ molecule concentrating at nuclei, e.g. $\delta(r-R)$, the potential energy is minimized. By the uncertainty principle,  the kinetic energy is quite large. This wavefunction neither corresponds to the ground state of H$_2^+$ nor the ground state/equilibrium of an ensemble H$_2^+$ molecules.

Comment: If you minimize Gibbs free energy, than you have equilibrium at constant pressure and temperature, etc... so the type of energy you choose corresponds to given ensemble. Roughly speaking.

Comment: No. None of the thermodynamic potentials is at its minimum at the equilibrium point of ANY system. This includes G.

Answer (score 3):

When you find a minimum in the **[thermodynamic potential energy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thermodynamic_potential)** of a system, you will have found an equilibrium point.

The key is the *thermodynamic potential* part. Depending on the constraints of the system (i.e. which thermodynamic state variables are held constant) the thermodynamic potential energy function will be different.

For example, in a system of a fixed number of particles at constant temperature and pressure (we would call it NPT), the **Gibbs free energy** is the thermodynamic potential, and it will be minimized at equilibrium.

For NVT (constant volume and temperature) the **Helmholtz free energy** is the thermodynamic potential, and that is what will be minimized at equilibrium.

In a system consisting of a rock dropped from a height above the ground, gravitational potential energy is the thermodynamic potential (I am abusing the language a little bit here) and it will be minimized at equilibrium (when the rock hits the ground).