# If chemical reactions occur because everything tends to a lower energy state, why is there such a thing as equilibrium?

Tags: equilibrium, kinetics, energy, entropy

It just doesn't make any sense, if a reaction occurs because the reactants go into a lower energy state, then there should be no such thing as equilibrium. right? Because that would mean that the products are going back into their higher energy states..... Is it just some sort of random chance that they keep changing form?

Comment: Everything tends to a lower energy state, that's the reason spontaneous reaction occur without absorbing any energy. But when you  supply energy to some substances they will show some molecular activity.

Comment: So there is equilibrium because the products re-absorb the energy? But why? why don't they just release that energy in some other form besides enthalpy?

Comment: @bluebellae I'm afraid your comment is bad, not the question.

Comment: See http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/4/gibbs-free-energy-minimum-or-zero

Comment: http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/44919/in-equilibrium-if-bonds-are-constantly-being-created-and-broken-where-does-the and http://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/7260/does-minimizing-any-type-of-energy-always-predict-a-state-of-equilibrium are related

Comment: Going to the lowest _free_ energy state is not the same thing as minimizing potential energy.  In classical thermodynamics, the idea that equilibrium can't exist because it isn't the lowest-energy state could be true, but only at zero kelvin.